# When is chmod 777 justified?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I know that one should avoid setting file/folder permissions to 777 and instead use a more granular approach.

I would like to know, if there are specific cases when using `chmod 777` on a webserver is justified.

Comment: chmod 777 on *what*?  i.e. a directory in the web server path, or somewhere else.  Without a specific example, the only possible answer is one of 'maybe' or 'possibly' or 'probably'.

Comment: In which situation are you really interested?  There are going to be different answers depending on what environment you're in (corporate, small business, public facing server, personal VM, etc).

Comment: If you are struggling to find valid cases, then surely you've already answered your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are always ways to tighten up permissions appropriately.

Comment: If you have a directory to which everyone in the universe genuinely needs full access, then 777 is justified.  I think it's naive to say it's *never* required.  Sure, it should be unusual and by exception only, but it's not inconceivable.

Comment: On a web server? Again, better ways.

Comment: @EightBitTony:  Even then, the directory should probably be set to **1**777 like `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/`.  The [sticky bit](https://serverfault.com/questions/10353) allows a world-writable directory, while preventing users from deleting each others' files.  (If the users trust each other so much that they _should_ delete each others' files, then they should probably get their own group and a 0770 directory to play in.)